# INET EnergyConsumer module's parameters new value never takes effect at runtime

Tags: c++, omnet++, inet

I would request your help on this issue I'm facing on. Actually, I want to change the energyConsumer module's parameters at run time.
The scenario is that I should specify an amount of energy when the nodes are transmitting or receiving depending on the state of the radio.
I came through with the help of this piece of code. Thanks to that, the value of the designated parameters are well settled but the problem is that they never took effect as wished.

The parameterization of the energyConsumer module is s follow :

```
        cModule *module = getGrandParentModule->getParentModule()->getSubmodule("node",myCHIndex);
        cModule *energyConsumerCHModule =  module->getSubmodule("wlan",0)->getSubmodule("radio")->getSubmodule("energyConsumer");
        StateBasedEpEnergyConsumer *energconsumption = check_and_cast<StateBasedEpEnergyConsumer *>(energyConsumerCHModule);

        cModule *chmodule =  module->getSubmodule("generic")->getSubmodule("np");
        Sim *chsim = check_and_cast<Sim *>(chmodule);

        cPar *receivingPower    = &energconsumption->par("receiverReceivingPowerConsumption");
        EV_DEBUG <<"MY CLUSTER HEAD RECEIVING POWER IS :  "<<receivingPower->doubleValue()<<endl;
        EV_DEBUG <<"NEW VALUE CALCULATED : "<<((chsim->EnergyCH_RX)*bitrate)/(K)<<endl;
        receivingPower->setDoubleValue(((chsim->EnergyCH_RX)*bitrate)/(K));
        EV_DEBUG <<"MY CLUSTER HEAD RECEIVING POWER APPLIED IS :  "<<receivingPower->doubleValue()<<endl;

        EV_DEBUG <<"**************************************************************"<<endl;

        cPar *transmittingPower = &energyconsumption->par("transmitterTransmittingPowerConsumption");
        EV_DEBUG <<"MY CURRENT TRANSMITTING POWER IS :  "<<&energyconsumption->par("transmitterTransmittingPowerConsumption")<<endl;
        EV_DEBUG <<"NEW VALUE CALCULATED : "<<(EnergyToCH*bitrate)/(K)<<endl;
        transmittingPower->setDoubleValue((EnergyToCH*bitrate)/(K));
        EV_DEBUG <<"MY CURRENT TRANSMITTING POWER APPLIED IS :  "<<&energyconsumption->par("transmitterTransmittingPowerConsumption")<<endl;
```

THE OUTPUT IS AS PER THE IMAGES :
[image: Simulation output of the above code]

But as you can see, no energy consumption happens (the energyStorage module still keeps the initial energy provided, 0.5J) despite there being some well-defined value.

THE NEXT IMAGE IS THE STATE OF THE ENERGY STORAGE MODULE:

[image: energySotorage State]

Could you please advise on how should I process it?

Many thanks for your support...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `StateBasedEpEnergyConsumer` module is not written in a way that it expects that certain parameters are changing during runtime (in fact almost none of the INET modules are). A parameter is usually read only once (usually during the initialization phase). After that point they usually store the value of the parameter in an internal member variable and they do not care about any change in the future. (you can check that in `StateBasedEpEnergyConsumer.cc`).

If you want to change the energy consumption values during runtime, you should write your own EnergyConsumer module by implementing the `power::IEpEnergyConsumer` interface. (or modify the current implementation by adding a `handleParameterChange()` method to store the actual new value in the member variable.

Comment: Many thanks, @Rudi for your details. I have already read the manual and heard about the `handleParameterChange()` method but failed to successfully implement it. Now again you raise up this means to go. So, I would ask you if you can assist me more by elaborating through a piece of code how I can use this method.

Comment: Search INET for `handleParameterChange`. You will find ample of examples.

Comment: OK, Thanks. I will revert to give feedback.

Comment: Changing parameters here and there may not result the best software architecture. I would rather write a custom EnergyConsumer module that encapsulates all logic required to determine the actual consumption power values if they are not constant. Modules that change unexpectedly other module's paramater can cause unexpected errors on long term.

Comment: To prevent surprises in the future, we have added a check to omnet (6pre14 or later) that will throw an error if you change programmatically a parameter value from C++ code, unless the parameter was not explicitly marked with `@mutable` in NED. It means that models must explicitly declare that a given parameter can be changed any time and the module's C++ code will handle it properly. Otherwise the parameter must be treated as `const` and an error will be thrown if you attempt to change it.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @Rudi. I went through the first piece of advice, `write your own EnergyConsumer module by implementing the power::IEpEnergyConsumer interface` and it works quite for my needs. However, I still failed to implement the `handleParameterChange()` method despite the varied implementation I saw across the INET package. I think I need an explanation of this method, How it works.

Comment: There is nothing interesting here. If you implement `handleParameterChange()` in a module, then whenever anyone in the simulation changes that parameter the simulator will call the `handleParameterChange()` method on that module, with the new value. What you do with the new value is up to you. Usually you would re-read the value and set your internal variables with the new value (i.e. the code would look somewhat similar what you would do in the `initialize()` method. This just a *notification* from the kernel that a parameter changed.

Comment: Thanks, @Rudi. I see my concern. `handleParameterChange()` method should be implemented in the module where the changes will occur. It works quite well now.

Comment: Just a bit of warning: with the next 6.0pre14 version, you will have to annotate each parameter with `@mutable` in the NED file where `handleParameterChange()` is properly implemented so it will be clear from the NED file whether you can change that parameter from C++.

Comment: Well recorded. Thanks for your precision. I'm sure to be growing with your help. I'm experiencing a wonderful experience with OMNeT++.